# Is there a way to store binary data (byte[]) in DocValues lucene search

Tags: lucene

iam use  lucene  .i want stroe image binary but dont stroe .
iam use this code

> error:cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'string'

```
 byte[] myByteArray = viewModel.Image;
    productDocument.Add(new Field("Image",  myByteArray, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

Comment: What version of lucene are you using?  The ctor you are using no longer exists in the latest version, and was deprecated in 4.0.  `DocValues` was introduced in 4.0, so if you are, indeed, using an earlier version, you obviously won't have access to it.

Comment: iam use ver 3.0 how use earlier version for nuget